# Knockout Editing with asp.net roles

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm a newbie to knockout and was wondering what the best approach using knockout with asp.net membership roles (mvc 4), I want to add a grid on the page and make it editable if the user is an administrator or just make it viewable if they are in a 'registered user' role? I don't want the user to be able to edit the page by changing the javascript using developer tools/firebug unless the only way to stop that is to check for role when post results back.

Thanks in advance, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use knockout for this. If a user is not an admin, they should not even be able to reach the page. Just use the `[Authorize]` attribute at the controller or the action level and specify what roles are allowed. *Any* JavaScript solution could easily be worked around given any industrious user access to user management despite their role.

Comment: I was thinking the same, the javascript hacks that can be in hence the reason to update and check the role within post back. But i guess it's a waste of resource. Thanks for the reply.